Flutter iOS File Sharing Error: "Failed to request default share mode" and "Client not entitled"
Im developing a Flutter application and encountering an issue when trying to share a contact file on an iOS device. The sharing functionality works fine on Android, but on iOS, I'm seeing errors related to entitlements and sandbox restrictions.
When I press the share button and the permission request screen pops up, when I give permisson, I get the following messages in the debug console:
Failed to request default share mode for fileURL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3DE61C91-8439-4A4F-ACCF-7BCEE3E21F43/Library/Caches/contact.vcf error:Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=1741, _LSFunction=runEvaluator}
Only support loading options for CKShare and SWY types.
error fetching item for URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3DE61C91-8439-4A4F-ACCF-7BCEE3E21F43/Library/Caches/contact.vcf : (null)
error fetching file provider domain for URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3DE61C91-8439-4A4F-ACCF-7BCEE3E21F43/Library/Caches/contact.vcf : (null)
error fetching item for URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3DE61C91-8439-4A4F-ACCF-7BCEE3E21F43/Library/Caches/contact.vcf : (null)
Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.primitiveattribute AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.frontboard AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.trustedtarget AND Target not hosted by originator)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.primitiveattribute AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.frontboard AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.trustedtarget AND Target not hosted by originator)}>
(501) personaAttributesForPersonaType for type:0 failed with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.mobile.usermanagerd.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.mobile.usermanagerd.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction.}
Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
elapsedCPUTimeForFrontBoard couldn't generate a task port
Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}
elapsedCPUTimeForFrontBoard couldn't generate a task port
Received port for identifier response: <(null)> with error:Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "Client not entitled" UserInfo={RBSEntitlement=com.apple.runningboard.process-state, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled, RBSPermanent=false}

below is the my method used
  Future<void> shareContact(
      BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> data, String type) async {
    try {
      // Check and request permissions for both Android and iOS
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        final status = await Permission.storage.status;
        if (!status.isGranted) {
          final result = await Permission.storage.request();
          if (!result.isGranted) {
            throw Exception('Storage permission denied');
          }
        }
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        final status = await Permission.photos.status;
        if (!status.isGranted) {
          final result = await Permission.photos.request();
          if (!result.isGranted) {
            throw Exception('Photos permission denied');
          }
        }
      }

      // Generate vCard or MeCard data
      final cardData =
          type == 'mecard' ? generateMeCard(data) : generateVCard(data);

      // Get the documents directory
      final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final filePath =
          '${directory.path}/contact.${type == 'mecard' ? 'mecard' : 'vcf'}';
      final file = File(filePath);

      // Write card data to the file
      await file.writeAsString(cardData, flush: true);

      // Validate file path and existence
      if (await file.exists()) {
      } else {
        throw Exception('File does not exist');
      }

      // Share the file
      await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(file.path)]);
    } catch (e) {
      if (context.mounted) {
        SnackbarMessages.showErrorMessage(context, 'An error occurred: $e');
      }
    }
  }```


